# Running gearman Worker PHP code in multiple machines

Tags: php, gearman

Im using multiple workers in my localhost Gearman server machine, where is all my code. 
Im thinking, if i run this worker elsewhere i must need to move all the the libraries im using to perform this task. Am i right?

Example: In this script im using FILE Class that also uses multiple libraries inside it.

```
namespace app\controllers;
use app\file\File;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$worker = new \GearmanWorker();
$worker->addServer();

$worker->addFunction('parse_file', function($job){
    echo "entrou no add function!<br>";
    print_r ($job->workload());
    sleep(2);
    new File($job->workload()); # this class parses the files content in database
});

while($worker->work())
{
  if ($worker->returnCode() != GEARMAN_SUCCESS)
  {
    echo "return_code: " . $worker->returnCode() . "\n";
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I don't quite understand the question. If you need to run the "employee" on a different server - you need to move the code. If you want to move Gearman on another server, you need add to the "addServer" - host

Comment: As move the code, you mean move all the libraries and classes used by the worker right? Is always like cloning my application for each machine?

Comment: It depends on what you need, and on how to structure your code. You can create worker.php file, copy and run. You can collect phar package and your code will be in a single file... But you can not run code from one machine to run on other machines, without any "copy"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes - you will need a copy of your libraries on each machine the workers will run on.  You will need the FILE class and any dependencies.

You only need one copy of the codebase per machine, but you can run multiple instances of workers.